# How can I assure that a component provided by me for web application is not used for multiple domains or websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, plugins

I am a ruby on rails developer and I have developed several plugins, may be i will be selling them to some web sites and they can use my plugin in there application. But i want to assure that the plugin code once given to them is not used for any other application, if they do so i must know where is it deployed.

I just need a way to track number of deployments, for a given plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Ruby is interpreted, so they can simply remove the tracking code from it, and use it where they want. You might want to build C extensions for ruby if you really want resellable components.

Comment: Can web services be an answer to my question. please provide sufficient pointers so that i am able to understand the workflow and utilize it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assure it. You can make it unprofitable by creating some obfuscated code, which will limit the use. On assumption that analyzing that code will cost a lot more, than just paying you another license. Of course that doesn't guarantee anything at all.

Comment: Web services ? can they solve this problem or REST API located at remote location only allowing some authorized web sites with information.

Comment: Well then how do i obfuscate the code, i cannot do it before hand as i will be providing them with plugin which must work.. please explain